# How to Get a Splash Form to timeout in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Can't seem to find an answer to this one on here.  Most likely very simply but as I'm only a delphi "Dabbler" I haven't been able to figure it out.
I have a Splash Screen which of course kicks in first but it also acts as a login screen. User enters their name and they get access.  However, If there is no input within say a 15 minute period of time I'd like the app to login in anyway with a default username and advise me that no actual user logged in.  Have most of that covered, Just can't figure out how to get it to timeout. I assume it has to be in the class function somwhere but..... Here is the code.  Thanks in advance guys.

```
    class function TSplashForm.Execute: boolean;
begin
  with TSplashForm.Create(nil) do
  try
    Result := ShowModal = mrOk;
  finally
    Free;
end;
end;

procedure TSplashForm.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edtLoginname.Text = UName then
    ModalResult := mrOK
  else
  begin
    ModalResult := mrNone;
    ShowMessage(edtLoginName.Text+' is an Incorrect Username.....Try AGAIN');
    edtLoginName.Text := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Run a timer. If it expires, close the form.

Comment: David. I assumed a Timer would be the answer but where do I put the code, in the Class Function I believe but do I use a REPEAT UNTIL statement  or { If (result = mrOK) or (MyTimer = xxxxx) then } do default login.....

Comment: Doesn't really matter. The timer can be anywhere. When it expires close the form.

Comment: Gotcha!   many thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a `TTimer` on the splash form, set its `Interval` to 15 minutes, and have its `OnTimer` event close the form. Each time the user types something, reset the timer.

```
procedure TSplashForm.edtLoginnameChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Timer1.Enabled:= true;
end;

procedure TSplashForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModalResult := mrIgnore;
end;

procedure TSplashForm.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edtLoginname.Text = UName then
    ModalResult := mrOK
  else begin
    ModalResult := mrNone;
    ShowMessage(edtLoginName.Text+' is an Incorrect Username.....Try AGAIN');
    edtLoginName.Clear;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
class function TSplashForm.Execute: Integer; 
begin
  with TSplashForm.Create(nil) do
  try
    Result := ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

case TSplashForm.Execute of
  mrOK: // user logged in...
  mrIgnore: // timed out...
else
  // cancelled ...
end;
```